# HTML, CSS, background showing inside div

Tags: html, css, background

i have body and background there. i have also image there. i want to hide image and show background only in area of the hidden image. just to make background'shape as image'shape.

anyone knows how can i make it? which functions, tools should i use?

i tried background-clip:content-box but it does not work.

thank you for any advice!

```
#field {
    background: url(../images/10.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-clip:content-box;
}
#img { 
position: relative;
top:0px;
z-index: -100;
}
```

[more or less that is the point of my thinking in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAW9I.png)

Comment: I'm having a hard time to understand what you're trying to do. Please click [edit] and improve your question.

Comment: Try edditing your post and then provide us with a snippet of HTML please, it is hard to grasp only looking at your CSS because you are using id's

Comment: Could you possibly draw or show something relevant to explain your question further? Your question is quite vague.

Comment: Please be more specific or even show an example.

Comment: i added an image, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're asking how to put a background only where the image is

Simply add a background-image to your image (which is ... tada! a transparent pixel!)

```
<img id="img" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
```

CSS:

```
#img{
   width: 300px; height: 300px;
   background: url(../images/10.png) 50% / cover;
}
```

Comment: exactly! thank you! but can i make similar trick with not transparent images ?